# Traverse over a string twice in regex

Tags: regex, perl

I have an input string something like (Actual string is much more complicated):

```
223001PAPA DUMMY
```

on this string i want to match the first 3 characters as one group and next 3 as another group and want to save the matches in variable's for further processing.

regex I used:

```
(.{3})(.{3}).*
```

[regex 101 example 1](https://regex101.com/r/fF8aN0/1)

Now on the same input string I would also want to match the whole string length i.e 16 in this case

```
(.{16}).*
```

[regex 101 example 2](https://regex101.com/r/fF8aN0/2)

But i want to do both these operations in a single regex, i.e one match should match the complete input string and save in a variable and then another 2 matches for first and second 3 characters as shown above, is it possible?
how can I proceed? Tried backreference did not help much

Comment: Why not using `string[start:end]` directly as you are using `python`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 ^((.{3})(.{3}).{10})
```

You can use this.

Here `group 1` will be `16 character string`

`group 2` will be first `3` characters.

`group 3` will be next `3` characters.

https://regex101.com/r/fF8aN0/3

When you use this with `re.findall` you get a `list` of `3` values which is defined above.

Comment: you guys are amazing. and regex is amazing!